# Investigating convergence of integral for certain parameters

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

Suppose we have an integral of the form,

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{b-1}[\log(1+x)]^{1+a}}{(1+x^2)^{c+b/2}}dx $$

I want investigate values of $a,b,c > 0$ for which this integral converges. Using the basic inequality, $\log(1+x) \leq x$ for $x > 0$, the integral is bounded by,

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{b-1}[\log(1+x)]^{1+a}}{(1+x^2)^{c+b/2}}dx \leq \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{a+b}}{(1+x^2)^{c+b/2}}dx = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+b+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(c-\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(c+\frac{b}{2}\right)}$$

(this integral was computed in Mathematica). So we can see that convergence holds if $c - \frac{a+1}{2} > 0$ or $a < 2c - 1$. Unfortunately this forces $c > \frac{1}{2}$. Is there a better bound than $\log(1+x) \leq x$ I can use? Ideally, I'd like to fix $b,c > 0$ and choose $a$ alone.

Comment: Is it $[\log(1+x)]^{1+a}?$

Comment: Yes, log(1+x) should be in brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x^p} =0$$

for all $p>0.$

---

Added later: In our integral there are possible problems at $x=0$ and at $\infty$ and nowhere else. But notice that on $(0,1],$ the integrand is bounded above by a constant times $x^{b-1}.$ Since $b-1>-1,$ $\int_0^1 x^{b-1}<\infty.$ So that's nothing to worry about.

What happens on $[1,\infty)?$ As $x\to \infty,$ we essentially have $x^{b-1-2c-b}$ times $[\ln(1+x)]^{1+a}.$ In other words, we have $x^{-1-2c}$ times $[\ln(1+x)]^{1+a}.$ But the point of the hint is that the $\ln$ term is less than any positive power of $x$ eventually. So $[\ln(1+x)]^{1+a}$ is less than $x^c$ for large $x.$ Therefore the integrand is bounded above by a constant times $x^{-1-c}$ for large $x.$ Thus the integral over $[1,\infty)$ converges.

It appears to me the given integral converges for all $a,b,c>0.$

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I will try to work with that.

Comment: I’ve been trying to work with the hint but unfortunately I’m still stuck. I was able to bound the integrand by $1/(1+x^2)^c$. This integral still only converges when $c > 1/2$. Is there a better bound I can use?

Comment: Thank you again! It didn’t occur to me to break up the integral like that.

Answer (score 0):

First, clearly,
$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{b-1}[\log(1+x)]^{1+a}}{(1+x^2)^{c+b/2}}\mathrm{d} x$ is convergent.

Second, since $x(1+x^2)^c \ge \frac{1+x}{2}(\frac{(1 + x)^2}{2})^c$ for all $x$ in $[1, \infty)$, we have
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{x^{b-1}[\log(1+x)]^{1+a}}{(1+x^2)^{c+b/2}}\mathrm{d} x
\le \int_1^\infty \frac{[\log(1+x)]^{1+a}}{\frac{1+x}{2}(\frac{(1 + x)^2}{2})^c}\mathrm{d} x$$
It is easy to prove that RHS is convergent. We are done.

Comment: Thank you! It didn’t occur to me to break up the integral like that.

Comment: @Flowsnake You are welcome.